# Moved a shared library, now I can't run any commands

Tags: 18.04, shared-library

I ran `sudo mv /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 ~`, which in retrospect, was  not the world's greatest idea.

Now, I can't do anything. Any commands I run fail with 
`error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I can't run `apt`, I can't even do an `ls`. I can't move the file back with `[sudo] mv ~/libpthread.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. I can't run `ldconfig`. Any ideas on how to undo this damage?

One possible relevant fact is that `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` also contained the file `libpthread-2.27.so`, which was perhaps symlinked with `libpthread.so.0` somehow?

I don't think it matters, but this is Ubuntu 18.04 running on WSL.

Comment: I can `cd` without error!

Comment: What happens if you type `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME ls`?

Comment: @steeldriver Same error :(

Comment: Try `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v`. Check `man ldconfig` for info.

Comment: I couldn't use `sudo` at all.

Answer (score 10):

Fortunately, I was able to fix my problem.

I wasn't able to use `sudo`, since it resulted in the error above. However, I was able to follow the directions [here](http://www.top-password.com/blog/reset-lost-root-password-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/) to make the terminal start as root. At that point, I was able to make a new symlink `ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0`.

I reset the user back to my personal account, and the problem was fixed.